# Firebase cloud function not triggering

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using this function with flutter to trigger a write to a notifications collection. But so far changing anything in the user requests collection does nothing:

```
from firebase_admin import firestore, initialize_app
import google.cloud.firestore
from firebase_functions import firestore_fn, https_fn, db_fn
from firebase_functions.firestore_fn import (
  on_document_created,
  on_document_deleted,
  on_document_updated,
  on_document_written,
  Event,
  Change,
  DocumentSnapshot,
)

initialize_app()

@https_fn.on_call(max_instances=10)
@on_document_updated(document="user_requests/{requestID}")
def paid_for_request(event: Event[Change[DocumentSnapshot]]) -> None:
    firestore_client: google.cloud.firestore.Client = firestore.client()
    firestore_client.document("notifications/test").set({
      "body": "Hello"
  })
```

Help if you notice what i should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have marked this Cloud Function as both an `on_call` and a `on_document_updated`.

Remove the `@https_fn.on_call()` and see if that resolves the issue.